# How to get names of all opened windows in my system using a vc++ application?

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to solve a problem, to display the names of all windows which are currently open.

I am using vc++ (dialog based app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this `GetWindow` API to traverse through the handles of windows displayed. Use `GetWindowText` API to get the caption title (if it has one).

```
HWND wnd = ::GetWindow( this->GetSafeHWND(), GW_HWNDFIRST );
if( !wnd )
{
   return;
}
CString csWindows = "";
do
{
    CString csText;
    ::GetWindowText( wnd, csText.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), MAX_PATH );
    csText.ReleaseBuffer();
    if( !csText.IsEmpty())
    {
        csWindows += csText + "\n";
    }
}while( wnd = ::GetWindow( wnd, GW_HWNDNEXT ));
AfxMessageBox( csWindows );
```

Above code should work. If you want only visible windows, use `::IsWindowVisible` API to check it.

**Update:**

> An application that calls GetWindow to perform this task risks being
>   caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a window that
>   has been destroyed. Using EnumWindows for top-level Windows and
>   EnumChildWindows for Child Windows or EnumThreadWindows for all
>   non-child windows associated with a thread is a preferred method.

Quoted from [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009)

Comment: thanks so much....

I hope this code also work


BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) {
    char buff[255];

    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
       GetWindowText(hWnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);

    return 0;
}

Comment: EnumWindows enumerates all the top-level windows displayed. It should work if that is what you want.